# Create object on page_load and pass to JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have an asp.net page and the JQuery date picker. On page load, I want to look at some config and create an object of dates to not include and then pass that to my JQuery in an external .js file. Is there a way to do this? How?

EDIT:
I'd like to pass a Class object

Comment: What will your object of dates look like? Why do you need to pass it in an external .js file?

Answer (score 0):

How about executing an `AJAX request` on page load and reading the values from config file in the service call.